# Two points inside a circle

Tags: mathematics, geometry

Two points are randomly chosen inside a circle. Is it always possible to draw a straight line through each point, such that they subdivide the circle into 3 regions of equal area?

**Bonus**: can the lines subdivide the circle into 4 regions of equal area?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unless I'm missing something obvious, the answer to the original question is:

> **No**
>
>  To have only three regions, the two lines cannot intersect inside the circle, so the each line must independently divide the area into 1/3 and 2/3 regions.
>  But if one point is at the centre of the circle, any line through it bisects the circle, so cannot produce the required 1/3 region.

And the answer to the bonus question is:

> Also **No**
>
>  Any adjacent pair of regions must sum to 1/2 the total area, and are separated by one of the two lines. From this it follows that both lines must bisect the circle.
>  All lines that bisect a circle pass through its centre, so both lines must do so. And to divide the circle into four equal regions, they must be perpendicular.
>  This will not be possible for most pairs of points, but for a specific counter-example, consider any pair of points on the circumference that are not 90 degrees apart.

Comment: This is correct. Ok it was a little too easy. I've now added a bonus question.

Comment: Sorry, missed your bonus answer which is quicker than mine.

Comment: Why is this not a counterexample to your answer to the original question? https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJcTH.png Is there a requirement for what a "region" means that wasn't stated in the question?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica Region wasn't defined as anything special/clever here, so I used the common/simple interpretation. I would not consider your two green areas (connected only at a corner) to be a single region, unless the OP explicitly defined region to allow that sort of solution.